# getting weird errors while trying to build ios app using flutter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

this is my debug log

```
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode
project: P7NL527WV9
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           75.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.
    7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.m:575:23: warning: 'requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback' is
    deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            configuration.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = true;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback
    In module 'WebKit' imported from
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.
    7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.h:6:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneO
    S14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebViewConfiguration.h:213:28:
    note: 'requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property (nonatomic) BOOL requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback
    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback", ios(9.0, 10.0));
                               ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.
    7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.m:587:23: warning: 'requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback' is
    deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            configuration.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = false;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback
    In module 'WebKit' imported from
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.
    7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.h:6:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneO
    S14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebViewConfiguration.h:213:28:
    note: 'requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property (nonatomic) BOOL requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback
    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback", ios(9.0, 10.0));
                               ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.
    7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.m:575:23: warning: 'requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback' is
    deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            configuration.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = true;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback
    In module 'WebKit' imported from
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.
    7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.h:6:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneO
    S14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebViewConfiguration.h:213:28:
    note: 'requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property (nonatomic) BOOL requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback
    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback", ios(9.0, 10.0));
                               ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.
    7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.m:587:23: warning: 'requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback' is
    deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            configuration.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = false;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback
    In module 'WebKit' imported from
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.
    7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.h:6:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneO
    S14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebViewConfiguration.h:213:28:
    note: 'requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property (nonatomic) BOOL requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback
    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback", ios(9.0, 10.0));
                               ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:34:16: warning: unnecessary check
    for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariBrowserOptions: Options<SafariViewController> {
                 ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:66:12: warning: unnecessary check
    for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin,
    SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/InAppBrowser/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:557:13: warning: setter for
    'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]
                UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle(rawValue:
                previousStatusBarStyle)!
                ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:695:34: error: value of type 'WKPDFConfiguration'
    has no member 'rect'
                    pdfConfiguration.rect = CGRect(x: rect["x"]!, y: rect["y"]!, width:
                    rect["width"]!, height: rect["height"]!)
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:698:9: error: cannot find 'createPDF' in scope
            createPDF(configuration: pdfConfiguration) { (result) in
            ^~~~~~~~~
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:713:29: error: incorrect argument label in call
    (have 'completionHandler:', expected 'dataCompletionHandler:')
            createWebArchiveData(completionHandler: { (result) in
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                 dataCompletionHandler
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1237:33: error: extra arguments at positions #2,
    #3 in call
            super.evaluateJavaScript(javaScript, in: frame, in: contentWorld, completionHandler:
            completionHandler)
                                    ^
    WebKit.WKWebView:46:15: note: 'evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)' declared here
        open func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: ((Any?,
        Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
                  ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1237:94: error: cannot convert value of type
    '((Result<Any, Error>) -> Void)?' to expected argument type '((Any?, Error?) -> Void)?'
            super.evaluateJavaScript(javaScript, in: frame, in: contentWorld, completionHandler:
            completionHandler)
                                                                                       ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1254:15: error: value of type 'WKWebView' has no
    member 'callAsyncJavaScript'
            super.callAsyncJavaScript(functionBody, arguments: arguments, in: frame, in:
            contentWorld, completionHandler: completionHandler)
            ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:34:16: warning: unnecessary check
    for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariBrowserOptions: Options<SafariViewController> {
                 ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:66:12: warning: unnecessary check
    for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin,
    SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/Types/URLCredential.swift:14:25: warning: comparing non-optional value of type
    '[Any]' to 'nil' always returns true
            if certificates != nil {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/Util.swift:86:25: warning: 'spotlightSuggestion' was deprecated in iOS 10.0:
    renamed to 'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion'
                    return .spotlightSuggestion
                            ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/Util.swift:86:25: note: use 'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion' instead
                    return .spotlightSuggestion
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/Util.swift:121:31: warning: 'spotlightSuggestion' was deprecated in iOS 10.0:
    renamed to 'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion'
                if type.contains(.spotlightSuggestion) {
                                  ^
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/Util.swift:121:31: note: use 'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion' instead
                if type.contains(.spotlightSuggestion) {
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                  WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion
    /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/i
    os/Classes/Util.swift:216:21: warning: immutable value 'j' was never used; consider replacing
    with '_' or removing it
                    for j in ipv6.count...8 {
                        ^
                        _
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Encountered error while building for device.
```

These are the plugins/packages used in the code

flutter_remix: ^0.0.3
flutter_vector_icons: ^1.0.0

## Firebase

firebase_core: ^1.1.0
firebase_auth: ^3.0.0
firebase_messaging: ^11.2.6
firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.6.0+7
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.7
firebase_storage: ^10.2.6

## State Management

get: ^4.1.4
get_storage: ^2.0.2

## Fonts

google_fonts: ^2.1.0

## User Interface

statusbarz: ^1.0.2
lottie: ^1.0.1
flutter_hud: ^0.3.0
multiavatar: ^0.1.5
flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
carousel_slider: ^4.0.0-nullsafety.0
octo_image: ^1.0.0+1
cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
dropdown_search: ^2.0.1
shimmer: ^2.0.0
animated_background: ^2.0.0
image_picker_type: ^1.0.1
flutter_gradient_colors: ^2.0.0-prerelease-nullsafety
flutter_shimmer: ^2.0.0-prerelease-nullsafety
draggable_home: ^1.0.2
timelines: ^0.1.0
syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^19.2.47-beta

## Utils

random_string_generator: ^2.0.0
path_provider: ^2.0.2
image: ^3.0.2
jiffy: ^5.0.0
url_launcher: ^6.0.7
package_info: ^2.0.2
flutter_contact: ^0.9.1+8
permission_handler: ^8.1.2
contactor_picker: ^0.0.4
flutter_native_contact_picker: ^0.0.3
nanoid: ^1.0.0
share_plus: ^3.0.4
package_info_plus: ^1.0.5
crisp: ^0.3.1

## Gateway

flutter_paystack: ^1.0.5+1
flutterwave: ^1.0.1
nravepay: ^1.0.5+1

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with an included dependency.

> module 'WebKit' imported from
> /Users/bhbj/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.
> 7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.h

Maybe you have imported a PDF webview package that is not compatible with iOS, or you need permissions to use it, normally you can add them in **Info.plist** file.